# OpenSQL uses additives that can only be used with a fixed point arithmetic flag?

Tags: abap, opensql

I keep having an error message for the selection below. What I have done is creating a global structure, then declaring a structure and a table in the program as **`TYPE`** `table`, as it is seen below:

```
DATA: gt_add_data_08 TYPE TABLE OF zsd_s_z5_9910_9900_08,
      gs_add_data_08 TYPE zsd_s_z5_9910_9900_08.
```

The selection that I have problem is below:

```
   SELECT gt_add_data_08~bi_desc1,
           gt_add_data_08~bi_desc2,
           gt_add_data_08~herkl,
           gt_add_data_08~herkl_t,
           gt_add_data_08~tempb,
           gt_add_data_08~tbtxt,
           vbdpl~lfimg,
           vbdpl~vrkme,
           vbdpl-charg
      INTO TABLE gs_add_data_08
      FROM gt_add_data_08
      INNER JOIN vbdpl ON
      vbdpl~posnr = gt_add_data_08~posnr,
      vbdpl~vbeln = gt_add_data_08~vbeln
      WHERE vbdpl~spras = 'EN'.
```

The selection is supposed to join two tables, thus `gt_add_data_08` and `vbdpl` into `gs_add_data_08`, with the condition that `spras` must be in English. The error that is show to me is:

> This Open SQL statement uses additives that can only be used with a fixed point arithmetic flag enabled (e.g. CASE Expression, Host variables in expressions, ...)

May anyone know where the problem may be that is showing to me this error?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your question is all about the meaning of "fixed point arithmetic flag enabled". It's a program flag described a lot in the Web.

Comment: By the way, for your information, the language code in ABAP-based systems is stored in database tables using 1 character only, not 2. English corresponds to code 'E'. It's usually bad practice to hard-code, better use the user's logon language.

Comment: Disabling the fixed point arithmetic flag [is obsolete](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abennon_fixed_point_obsolete.htm)!

Comment: Are you trying to do a SELECT on an *internal* table? You can only use SELECT on database tables.